# How to sort a dictionary with multiple inputs

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary called language list with 2 items: suburb and language.
Each suburb may have more than 1 language.

This is what is in the dictionary "languagelist":
('Edgecumbe', 'Farsi, English'), ('Junction Triangle', 'English, Mandarin'), ('Guildwood', 'Mandarin, English'), ('Greenmeadows', 'English')

The user enters a suburb eg. Edgecumbe
I need to display the languages for that suburb in alphabetical order eg
Languages: English, Farsi

I can only seem to sort the "suburb" item, but cannot sort the languages for that suburb.

How do I display only the languages for the suburb entered by user?

This is the current line of code to display:

```
print('Languages: ' + languagelist[suburb])
```

But it is not sorted properly. It is displaying:
Languages: Farsi, English

A snip of my current code is:

```
suburbs={} languagelist={} b=[] suburb=input('Suburb: ') 
for line in open('census.txt'): line=line.split(',') 
if line[3] not in suburbs: suburbs[line[3]] = line[3] a=line[4]a=a[:-1] languagelist[line[3]]= a elif line[3] 
in suburbs: suburbs[line[3]] = suburbs[line[3]] a=line[4] a=a[:-1]
if a not in languagelist[line[3]]: a=line[4] a=a[:-1] languagelist[line[3]]= languagelist[line[3]] + ', ' + a b=languagelist[line[3]] b.split(', ') languagelist[line[3]]=[] languagelist[line[3]]=b 
else: continue while suburb: if suburb not in suburbs: 
print('No data found for ' + suburb + '.')       
else:print('Languages:'+str(sorted(languagelist.suburb)))suburb=input('Suburb: ')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some code that you have written for this?

Comment: Your `languagelist` does not look like a Python dictionary, it looks like a tuple of tuples.

Comment: suburbs={}
languagelist={}
b=[]

suburb=input('Suburb: ')
for line in open('census.txt'):
  line=line.split(',')
  if line[3] not in suburbs:
    suburbs[line[3]] = line[3]
       a=line[4]
    a=a[:-1]
    languagelist[line[3]]= a
  elif line[3] in suburbs:
    suburbs[line[3]] = suburbs[line[3]]
    a=line[4]
    a=a[:-1]

Comment: if a not in languagelist[line[3]]:
      a=line[4]
      a=a[:-1]
      languagelist[line[3]]= languagelist[line[3]] + ', ' + a
      b=languagelist[line[3]]
      b.split(', ')
      languagelist[line[3]]=[]
      languagelist[line[3]]=b    
    else:
      continue
while suburb:    
  if suburb not in suburbs:
    print('No data found for ' + suburb + '.')
  else:
        print('Languages: ' + str(sorted(languagelist.suburb)))
  suburb=input('Suburb: ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you start with

```
languagelist = dict([('Edgecumbe', 'Farsi, English'), ('Junction Triangle', 'English, Mandarin'), ('Guildwood', 'Mandarin, English'), ('Greenmeadows', 'English')])
```

Then, for any `place`, the sorted languages spoken at that place is

```
', '.join(sorted(languagelist[place].split(', ')))
```

---

Of course, it would be *much* better if you just use a dictionary mapping places into what you want to begin with.

Comment: That sorts it correctly, but is displaying the square brackets.
Languages: ['English', 'Farsi']

Can we remove unwanted characters so that it returns:
Languages: English, Farsi